# Compilation fails with sln file loaded with Roslyn, but compiles in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, compilation, loading, roslyn, solution

I'm making a tool, and using Roslyn to load a solution file and then to
get the compilation for the contained projects.

But some errors arise (5000+)... these are few of them:

- CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported
- CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The following code has got two tries:

- **#1 - trying to compile right away** - what I tried in a first moment... this one has got 5000+ errors
- **#2 - compiling adding system references** - what I tried to make it work, and it did work... but not as expected

The code:

```
var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
var solution = await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(@"C:\Projects\MyLib\MyLib.sln");

var sortedProject = solution
    .GetProjectDependencyGraph()
    .GetTopologicallySortedProjects()
    .Select(solution.GetProject);

foreach (var project in sortedProject)
{
    // 
    // #1 - trying to compile right away
    //
    var compilation1 = await project.GetCompilationAsync();
    var diag1 = compilation1.GetDiagnostics();

    // 
    // #2 - compiling adding system references
    // 
    var assemblyPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);
    var project2 = project.AddMetadataReferences(
        new[]
                    {
                        MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(
                            Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "mscorlib.dll")),
                        MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(
                            Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "System.dll")),
                        MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(
                            Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "System.Core.dll")),
                    });

    var compilation2 = await project2.GetCompilationAsync();
    var diag2 = compilation2.GetDiagnostics();
}
```

Roslyn version being used: 1.0.0.0-beta2

**The question is:**

Since I have loaded a valid solution file, saved with *Visual Studio 2012*,
targeting *.Net Framework v4.5* and compiling with success in the IDE...
**why do I have to add system references to make it work?**.

I expected it to come with the references already... the system references to the correct
*.Net Framework* version. It means that even **#2 won't work always, because I'd have to
locate the correct *.Net Framework* version files**, instead of using the ones of the tool I am
currently compiling.

**EDIT**

Here is the `csproj` file contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{E8757858-B17B-43D4-AA13-412E552386DC}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>DataStructures</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>DataStructures</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <SolutionDir Condition="$(SolutionDir) == '' Or $(SolutionDir) == '*Undefined*'">..\</SolutionDir>
    <RestorePackages>true</RestorePackages>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug.net45\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG;net45</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release.net45\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;net45</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Release.net45\DataStructures.XML</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>masb.public.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Continuous\ContinuousSet.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Continuous\ContinuousSetEqualityComparer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Continuous\Interval.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Continuous\ISetOperator.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Continuous\PointState.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Continuous\RedundancyType.cs" />
    <Compile Include="EnumerableExtensions.cs" />
    <Compile Include="DictionaryExtensions.cs" />
    <Compile Include="IImmutable.cs" />
    <Compile Include="IImmutablePrototype.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Immutable\FuncCached.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Immutable\IImmutableSpecificTreeBuilderWithContext.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Immutable\IImmutableTreeBuilderWithContext.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Immutable\IMayBeImmutable.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Immutable\ImmutableSpecificTreeBuilderWithContext.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Immutable\ImmutableTreeBuilderWithContext.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Immutable\ImmutableTreeBuilderWithContextExtensions.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Immutable\IReadableForest.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Immutable\IImmutableSpecificTreeBuilder.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Immutable\IImmutableTreeBuilder.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Immutable\ImmutableCollection.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Immutable\ImmutableForestExtensions.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Immutable\ImmutableSpecificTreeBuilder.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Immutable\ImmutableTreeBuilder.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Immutable\ImmutableTreeBuilderExtensions.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Immutable\TreeBuildingContextBase.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Immutable\TreeBuildingContext.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Immutable\Tree\Branch.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Immutable\Tree\INodeFactory.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Immutable\Tree\INonRoot.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Immutable\Tree\Node.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Immutable\ImmutableForest.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Immutable\Tree\IBranch.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Immutable\Tree\ILeaf.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Immutable\Tree\INode.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Immutable\Tree\IRoot.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Immutable\Tree\Leaf.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Immutable\Tree\NodeExtensions.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Immutable\Tree\NonRoot.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Immutable\Tree\Root.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Immutable\Tree\RootBranch.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Immutable\Tree\RootLeaf.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Immutable\ImmutableTree.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Immutable\Tree\Visitor.cs" />
    <Compile Include="JetBrains.Annotations\JetBrains.Annotations.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Monads\IOption.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Monads\None.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Monads\OptionExtensions.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Monads\Some.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="SystemExtensions\ObjectExtensions.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="masb.public.snk" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets" Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" />
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets'))" />
  </Target>
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

Comment: What kind of projects? What errors?

Comment: C# projects (csproj)... all errors are reference errors... I have edited the question and added a few.

Comment: Approach number one *should* work. If you debug, do the projects get any references?  Are any of the projects Portable Class Libraries?

Comment: They are not PCL projects. The target framework of the csproj is `v4.5`. When debuggin, there are no `MetadataReferences` in #1. But I can compile it using VS2012. If I open the file in a text editor, the references are there. I'll edit the question and post the `csproj` contents.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure what's going on - any chance you could share the particular project you're trying to open with me (privately by email) so that we can take a look?

Comment: Both are open source: the solution I'm trying to load is in  
[masbicudo/data-structures-net](https://github.com/masbicudo/data-structures-net/blob/master/DataStructures.net45.sln);
the contained project is [DataStructures.net45.csproj](https://github.com/masbicudo/data-structures-net/blob/master/DataStructures/DataStructures.net45.csproj);
and the tool that reads the solution and project is 
[masbicudo/NuGet.Multiple.Targeting.Tool](https://github.com/masbicudo/NuGet.Multiple.Targeting.Tool).

Comment: The [line that compiles the project is this](https://github.com/masbicudo/NuGet.Multiple.Targeting.Tool/blob/c13a2be300fbcf5b9207af36ae570b2860b40c75/Masb.NuGet.Multiple.Targeting.Tool/Program.cs#L85).

Comment: I'll try to isolate the problem later... I can't do it right now.

Comment: I found the answer... =)

Answer (score 2):

I finally found an answer... I was using .Net Framework 4.6 preview to make the tool.

I uninstalled Visual Studio 2015 already, but not the framework 4.6.

So I mistakenly used it when creating the tool project, by selecting the .Net framework 4.5.3 in Visual Studio 2013 (it appears inside VS2013 after installing VS2015 CTP).

By switching the framework to 4.5 it works and loads the `MetadataReferences` correctly.